# SQL Query for finding rows with same set of values

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

Lets assume I have following table

```
Customer_ID  Item_ID
1            A
1            B
2            A
2            B
3            A
```

What I need is to find customers that purchased the same set of items.
Output:

```
Customer_id  Customer_id
id1          id2
```

(id1 < id2)

If there are more than two customers with same set of items, for example three, output must be next:

```
Customer_id  Customer_id
id1          id2
id2          id3
id1          id3
```

Thanks

Comment: do you have sql server 2012?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this has an enumID in the middle but is the same thing

```
with cte as ( SELECT [sID], [enumID], [valueID], count(*) over (partition by [sID], [enumID]) as ccount
                FROM [docMVenum1] 
               WHERE [sID] < 10000 ) 
select [cte1].[sID], [cte2].[sID], [cte1].[enumID] -- , [cte1].[valueID], [cte1].[ccount]
  from cte as [cte1] 
  join cte as [cte2] 
    on [cte1].[sID] < [cte2].[sID] 
   and [cte1].[enumID]  = [cte2].[enumID]
   and [cte1].[valueID] = [cte2].[valueID]
   and [cte1].[ccount]  = [cte2].[ccount]
 group by [cte1].[sID], [cte2].[sID], [cte1].[enumID], [cte1].[ccount]
having count(*) =  [cte1].[ccount]
 order by [cte1].[sID], [cte2].[sID] --, [cte1].[enumID], [cte1].[valueID];
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case :

```
create table CustomerAA (
    Customer_Id int ,
    ItemId varchar(10)
    );

Insert Into CustomerAA(Customer_Id,ItemId) values(1,'A')
Insert Into CustomerAA(Customer_Id,ItemId) values(1,'B')
Insert Into CustomerAA(Customer_Id,ItemId) values(2,'A')
Insert Into CustomerAA(Customer_Id,ItemId) values(2,'B')
Insert Into CustomerAA(Customer_Id,ItemId) values(3,'A')
```

You can use `Left Join` like above :

```
Select Distinct C1.Customer_Id , C2.Customer_Id
From CustomerAA As C1
Left Join CustomerAA As C2 on ( C1.ItemId = C2.ItemId )
Where
    ( C1.Customer_Id < C2.Customer_Id )
```

Or You can use `Inner Join` :

```
Select Distinct C1.Customer_Id , C2.Customer_Id
From CustomerAA As C1
Inner Join CustomerAA As C2 on ( C1.ItemId = C2.ItemId )
Where
    ( C1.Customer_Id < C2.Customer_Id )
```

Or

```
Select Distinct C1.Customer_Id , C2.Customer_Id
From CustomerAA As C1
Inner Join CustomerAA As C2 
    on ( 
           ( C1.ItemId = C2.ItemId ) 
           And 
           ( C1.Customer_Id < C2.Customer_Id ) 
       )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select C1.Customer_ID , C2.Customer_ID 
from table C1 
inner join table C2 on C1.Customer_ID < C2.Customer_ID and C1.Item_ID =Item_ID
```

Comment: C1.Item_ID = C2.Item_ID doesn't mean that sets are equal.

In example above Customer 1 and Customer 2 has same set of items.
But 2nd and 3rd aren't equal.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. The idea is to make use of an outer join and the fact that count ignores null

```
select t1.customer_id, t2.customer_id
from tbl t1
left join tbl t2
on t1.customer_id < t2.customer_id
and t1.item_id = t2.item_id
group by t1.customer_id, t2.customer_id
having count(t1.item_id) = count(t2.item_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution of my problem.
Firstly, I've created temporary table. This teable has column with number of different items, which each customer purchased.
It looks like this:

```
Customer_ID Item_Id num
1           A       2
1           B       2 
2           A       2
2           B       2
3           A       1
```

Query is next

```sql
DECLARE @tmp TABLE 
(
    Customer_ID int,
    Item_ID nvarchar(max),
    num int
)

INSERT INTO @tmp 
SELECT tbl.Customer_Id, tbl.ItemId, A.num
FROM tbl
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT Customer_Id,  COUNT(DISTINCT ItemId) AS num
    FROM tbl 
    GROUP BY Customer_Id) A 
ON tbl.Customer_Id = A.Customer_Id
```

After that, I use next query

```sql
SELECT t1.Customer_Id, t2.Customer_Id
FROM @tmp t1
INNER JOIN @tmp t2
ON t1.Customer_Id < t2.Customer_Id AND t1.Item_ID = t2.Item_ID
GROUP BY t1.Customer_Id, t1.num, t2.Customer_Id, t2.num 
HAVING COUNT(t1.Item_ID) = COUNT(t2.Item_ID) AND
    t1.num = COUNT(t1.Item_ID) AND
    t2.num = COUNT(t2.Item_ID)
```

So the result will be

```
Customer_ID Customer_ID 
1           2
```